The IHostedService.StopAsync method is not called when an ECS task is stopped because the application is handling the SIGTERM signal sent by ECS
I have created a background service using .NET 6, and the StopAsync() method is expected to be called when stopping the service locally using CTRL+C and when the ECS task is stopped on AWS. Currently, it works fine locally, but the StopAsync() method is never called when the service is stopped on an ECS task created using the Fargate launch type.
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
   private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

   public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
   {
       _logger = logger;
   }

   protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
   {
       while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
       {
           _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
           await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
       }
   }

   public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
       _logger.LogInformation("StartAsync called");
       return Task.CompletedTask;
   }

   public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
        _logger.LogInformation("StopAsync called");
         return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
}

As per the Microsoft document RunConsoleAsync should handle SIGTERM
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostinghostbuilderextensions.runconsoleasync?view=net-9.0-pp.
 var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices(s => s.AddHostedService<Worker>())
        .ConfigureLogging(l => l.AddConsole());
 await host.RunConsoleAsync();

and this is my docker file
 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
 WORKDIR /app
 COPY ./ ./
 RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
 WORKDIR /app
 COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
 ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestService.dll"]

What is the issue with my code ?

Why .NET 6 when .NET 9 is available and may fix this bug?

Currently I am using .Net 6 and needs to be fixed as part of .Net 6.
